# Running command-line commands in the background without opening a window

Tags: c++, winapi, background-process, createprocess

I'm running some command line script to encrypt a file using AxCrypt software.

My code compiles and runs fine, but when I check the file afterward, it has not been encrypted.

Here is the code:

```
LPCWSTR loc = L"C:\\\\Axantum\\\\AxCrypt\\\\AxCrypt";

STARTUPINFOW si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if (CreateProcessW(loc, const_cast<LPWSTR>(master), NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

The master variable contains the commands, loc contains the location of the AxCrypt program.

```
LPCWSTR axLocation = L" C:\\\\Axantum\\\\AxCrypt\\\\AxCrypt ";
LPCWSTR flags = L" -b 2 -e -k ";
LPCWSTR passcode = L" \"***************\" ";
LPCWSTR command = L" -z ";
LPCWSTR imagelocation = L"%pathName";
std::wstring mast = std::wstring(axLocation) + flags + passcode + command + imagelocation;
LPCWSTR master = mast.c_str();
```

Comment: Does `loc` point to _just_ the location of the executable or to the actual executable itself?

Comment: Divide and conquer. Remove AxCrypt from the equation. Execute some debug batch script instead so you can write debug output in it and find out what's going wrong.

Comment: You should not cast away the `const` from the `master` variable. Per the [CreateProcess documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `CreateProcessW` may modify the `lpCommandLine` argument - crashing your process if that memory is read-only.

Comment: loc points to the executable

Comment: Are you able to run `AxCrypt` from the command line and make it do what you want? What does `master` look like? The first field of the command line (2nd parameter) probably needs to be the program name.

Comment: I added master to the question

Comment: @AndrewMedico how do I get around this?

Comment: Is `CreateProcessW` succeeding? What is `%pathName`? Is the file you're encrypting in the same directory as your program?

Comment: i changed %pathName to (%c, pathName.c_str()) sorry for the confusion

Comment: I used the same commands in the cmd line and they worked, any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
LPCWSTR loc = L"C:\\\\Axantum\\\\AxCrypt\\\\AxCrypt";
```

This is wrong.  You have too many slashes in your literal.  It needs to be this instead:

```
LPCWSTR loc = L"C:\\Axantum\\AxCrypt\\AxCrypt";
```

Same goes with `axLocation`.

Also, you have unnecessary spaces in your various substrings.  Ultimately, you are creating this `master` command line, from the interpreter's perspective:

```
 C:\\Axantum\\AxCrypt\\AxCrypt  -b 2 -e -k  "***************"  -z %pathName
```

When it should look more like this:

```
 C:\Axantum\AxCrypt\AxCrypt -b 2 -e -k "***************" -z %pathName
```

Try something more like this instead:

```
LPCWSTR axLocation = L"C:\\Axantum\\AxCrypt\\AxCrypt";
LPCWSTR flags = L"-b 2 -e -k";
LPCWSTR passcode = L"***************";
LPCWSTR command = L"-z";
LPCWSTR imagelocation = L"%pathName";
WCHAR master[STRSAFE_MAX_CCH];
StringCchPrintfW(master, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, L"\"%s\" %s \"%s\" %s %s", axLocation, flags, passcode, command, imagelocation);

STARTUPINFOW si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

if (CreateProcessW(axLocation, master, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

Lastly, `%pathname` looks suspicious.  Is that supposed to be specified as-is like that?  Or is it supposed to be an environment variable instead?  If the latter, you are missing a percent sign:

```
%pathname%
```

`CreateProcess()` does not interpret environment variables, so if you need to pass such a variable then you would have to either:

1. resolve the variable yourself using `ExpandEnvironmentStrings()` before calling `CreateProcess()`.
2. have `CreateProcess()` launch `cmd.exe /C` and let it interpret environment variables for you, eg:

   ```
   StringCchPrintfW(master, STRSAFE_MAX_CCH, L"cmd /C \"%s\" %s \"%s\" %s %s", axLocation, flags, passcode, command, imagelocation);
   ```

Comment: It still compiles but doesn't encrypt the file at location "pathName"

Comment: Errors were my mistake, ignore